# Create multiple databases dynamically in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am a newbie in Microsoft Azure platform. I want to create multiple databases dynamically (We are developing multi-tenant model. So, Each organization should have their own database. Whenever an organization is registered with our system, we need to create a new database dynamically which should take the existing default database template as it's structure).Please provide some insights on this.